# How to get a innerTransaction from a instruction?

Tags: web3.js

I have:

```
const confirmedTx = await connection.getParsedTransaction(txHash, {
            maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
        });

   const instructions = confirmedTx.transaction.message.instructions;
   console.log(instructions[5]);


that returns: 


  accounts: [
    PublicKey [PublicKey(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)] {
      _bn: <BN: 6ddf6e1d765a193d9cbe146ceeb79ac1cb485ed5f5b37913a8cf5857eff00a9>
    },
    PublicKey [PublicKey(9nnLbotNTcUhvbrsA6Mdkx45Sm82G35zo28AqUvjExn8)] {
      _bn: <BN: 8297e544ff44406a13b7fa64c2cffa3ec6e15df8935e00c74170deaef013f37d>
    },
    PublicKey [PublicKey(5bEsUD6eJQ8j3pc26UzqaM6PASjDYZ7mha1TnWLYEtz4)] {
      _bn: <BN: 44342da1d5316f7f67707fcff53476ba91d541053ec344dccfbf837d53f05ab1>
    },
    PublicKey [PublicKey(BJQ8rw7G3gvXAixsQ9m1jUzGDweKgCBYmXroR9rgw8xX)] {
      _bn: <BN: 9909e706da68b20f633af95e96d27ddc13fd100f1e4466ac3490b28747e7cc10>
    },
  ],
  data: 'N6Jg6trErYYpJVAKrY9CyLPF3kBaGETBet28UuNDnpPYFEgVghLysGfnjuUoe7H',
  programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4)] {
    _bn: <BN: 479d55bf231c06eee74c56ece681507fdb1b2dea3f48e5102b1cda256bc138f>
  },
  stackHeight: null
}
```

This instruction[5] has a lot of innerTransactions that im trying to access and read.

ive already tried = instructions[5].innerInstruction[0],
but says: Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: It's `innerInstructions` with an `s` at the end. You have a typo in `instructions[5].innerInstruction[0]`

Comment: even with innerInstructions it returns the same error

Comment: Can you share a tx signature for me to take a look at?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit annoying, but the `innerInstructions` aren't stored at the instruction level, but rather on the `meta`, so you'd need to do:

```
for (const innerInstructions of confirmedTx.meta.innerInstructions) {
    if (innerInstructions.index === 5) {
        console.log(innerInstructions.instructions);
    }
}
```

You can read more about the structure at the docs for the `getTransaction` call https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction